# Python Selenium webdriver.Remote( hanging and clogging resources

Tags: python, multithreading, selenium

Good morning or Good evening depending where You are :)

I have an issue regarding My code which unfortunately due to length and using paid software I'm unable to share, altho the reason I'm asking My question after hours and hours of debugging seem to not be linked to any of those.

I have a code which does actions, it loads a profile, fires up the webdriver by starting the profile, attaches to it using

```
driver = webdriver.Remote(x=y,options=options)
```

and returns that driver for usage, after which there is a driver.get("website")

It all works well and smooth in threading, up untill a hundred executions, where the first page that loads the default (which i had set) about:blank page, this tab is a problem because not a single line of code is executed afterwards, so it doesn't reach the `driver.get("website")`

and it just remains there, not throwing any exception,sitting on that about:blank page.

new threads finish their course and other start just fine, continue the flow, do everything and after ten more threads another 2 "dead" about:blank pages open up, sitting there
fast forward another 10 15 or 20 threads, it only starts spawning dead about:blank pages while the already spawned ones (non dead) are continuing their course up untill only dead about:blank are still open and only new ones of such start opening.

I have tried any attempt of debugging that comes to my mind but not being able to write a single line of code that gets executed after and having no exception since the code just hangs there, i have no idea what might be causing the problem

things to note:

1. The other threads on exit close the open webdrivers and their connection
2. This happens independently of the amount of threads, I have not tested with only a couple because it would take a lot of times, but I have seen this happen with only 2 threads having actually finished part of the routine and having an active webdriver (so only 2 chromes open) and it happened (opened a third dead about:blank)

Please help
thank you kind souls.